# How to actually predict ONE parameter with Keras GRU on multi parameter weather time series

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

After training the GRU architecture in the Keras book (F. Chollet) on the Jena weather dataset (chapter #6), I am having difficulties understanding the prediction phase:

The last layer - Dense with no activation - outputs as expected, a stream of numbers:
Dimensions: Num of rows X 1.
I guess these are supposed to be the predictions, but it looks like a probability of ALL the 14 parameters. **Why only ONE prediction on the 14 parameters ?**

Problem is the input is num rows X num cols (14 parameters) and the predictions output **cannot be reshaped** into a 14 columns array - such as the weather data set contains.

Aren't the predictions supposed to have the **same number of columns** as the input, in the Jena Weather time sequence problem ?

If the predictions are on ALL 14 parameters and they have been strained thru a Dense layer with ONE unit - then this predictions' "stream" should be able to be reshaped back to num rows X num cols ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the define of generator function:

```
samples[j] = data[indices]
targets[j] = data[rows[j] + delay][1]
```

The target is the second column in the data, which should be the '"T (degC)"'. So this model predicts the temperature in Celsius degree.

Regarding to the last Dense layer, it has not activation function. So it just works as the simple linear regression model. The output is just summary of the output of previous layer multiple layer weights.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks NormanZhu for your clarification.
You pointed out correctly that the `[1]` in the generator `targets[j] = data[rows[j] + delay][1]` is the detail I've missed.
It is the only place in the generator that identifies the column to be used for fit/predict.
It makes sense and it allowed me to finally view the Predictions (blue)

[image]vs Reality (red) charts.
[image]

Comment: Here's my public kernel at Kaggle
https://www.kaggle.com/drscarlat/weather-predict-temperature-keras-gru/notebook